# Facebook Connect on iOS - Picture doesn't display with wall post

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I've set up Facebook connect with my app using the demo project provided by Facebook. Everything works great, except for the last little step...

- First of all, I login and get permissions.
- Next, I upload a picture. This works great, I can see the picture in my Facebook album like I should be able to.
- When this picture is uploaded, I get it's URL (returned by the FBRequest delegate). Copy pasting this URL into a web browser takes me directly to the image, so I know that this URL is correct.

**Here's where the problem is:**

- I now want to present this picture alongside a wall post. The wall post is fine, but the picture just doesn't seem to attach and the status is left as a plain text message.

Here's the code I'm using for the last part:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    NSString* picUrl = [result objectForKey:@"src_big"];  //this definitely returns the right URL

    if (picUrl)
    {
        NSString *message = @"Test status";
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       message, @"message", picUrl, @"picture", @"Look at my photo", @"name", nil];

        [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"facebook.Stream.publish" andParams:params
                          andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Try publishing with some random picture from the web. I remember something about Facebook not liking linking pictures from itself to wall posts.

Comment: @ssteinberg good idea, I just tried it but still doesn't seem to work. Will keep trying with a random image though to rule out that possibility.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fixed with the following code (after a lot of failed attempts). Facebook doesn't like the way I was trying it, you've got to do it all in just one step:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Test message", @"message", imageData, @"source", nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: If you're down-voting this, please at least say why... The above code works fine for me (as long as appropriate code is around it etc). If I'm really doing something wrong then I'd like to know as well.

Comment: If Someone wants to show uploaded image to user wall then make sure you have prompt for "publish_stream" access rights.

Comment: @Jordan:So we're you able to post picture on the wall?  I can only be able to post mine inside "Photos" within my app's album.

Comment: @user523234 I don't understand your question sorry - posting photos to an album will also be displayed on your wall and newsfeed consequentially. I was never trying to post photos to someone's wall, that's not what the question is about.

Comment: @Jordan Thank you for reply.  I am very new to fb.  But I just figured it as you said.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I'll remove my comment, but it's locked in until the next edit. Can you please edit the answer and I'll remove my neg vote?

Comment: Jordan- in my experience, Facebook is late to the game in uploading images from URLs, so yes, you have to post the local data contents of the image, and "publish" it to the me/photos.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet but to get this working I had to change @"/me/photos" to @"me/photos" in Jordan's answer above.  Very helpful though, not sure why it was down voted.